# Old kibana saved objects still showing after changing "kibana.index" config setting

Tags: kibana, kibana-5

**Steps to recreate:**

- default install and start of kibana (5.2.0)
- save a saved search, visualization or dashboard
- shutdown, change kibana.index in config/kibana.yml:

  - from ".kibana" (default)
  - to: ".kibananew"
- restart kibana and browse to management > saved objects

**Expected**: No saved searches, visualisations or dashboards to be present, because it should be looking for them in ".kibananew" which is empty?

**Actual**: They're still there.

Any help much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

So on second attempt this worked for me - i.e. I got the expected outcome above.

Either browser caching was an issue or I messed up!